# How to disable visual highlight of the current indent depth VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

It started doing it by itself, behavior is similar to indenticator extesion, but I never installed it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off rendering of the indent guides by:

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
```

or the colorcustomizations using:

```
"editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#fff8",
"editorIndentGuide.background": "#fff0",
```

The second customization above will make the inactive guides transparent and the first customization will make the current active indent guide a bright gray.